# SQL Full Backup job is taking too long to complete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

I am facing a strange issue with daily FULL backup. We have a total of 23 databases. We have 1.21 TB big database in this SQL server 2012 Standard Edition. We are taking daily FULL database backup for all databases.

For the last 2 days the backup is taking too long. After more than 10:30 hours it had only completed 67 % of the backup. Daily Full backup job completion time is normally 4 to 5 hours.

And the backup job is also showing `suspended` state.
I found last_wait_type is `ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION` for this backup job.

We have sufficient disk space available.

Can anyone make any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: Check the I/O performance on the disk where the backup files are begin written.  Ask your system admin / storage admin if something changed or if they notice any storage issues.

Comment: I have an small question in this, i am getting successful email alert with in 3 Sec. But backup is still running can you know why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

> I found last_wait_type is ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION for this backup job. We
>   have sufficient disk space available.

**This [blogpost](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/cause-high-duration-async_io_completion-waits/) from Paul Randal gives you most of the information regarding this wait stat**

> ...The official definition of ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION is ‘Occurs when a task
>   is waiting for I/Os to finish....
>
> ...Long-duration ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION waits commonly are from data backups....

A question similar to yours can be found on that same blog.
In his case a backup of a small database (1,5GB)  was taking over 15 minutes.

**Q**

> ...I’m facing a high level of ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION into one of my environments what is resulting in backups of small databases (around 1,5GB) to take more than 15 minutes. I have a feeling that it is related to low performance on the I/O
>   subsystem. But I’m not 100% confidente to go ahead on this diagnostic
>   to ask for analysis or changes on that.

**A**

> Yup – that’s what it is. Try doing a backup to nul, as that will give
>   you time taken to read from the data files. The difference is the time
>   being taken to write out the backup files – there’s your ammo.

This is the command to do that:

```
BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseName TO DISK = 'NUL'
```

And compare this with the  backup time you mentioned previously.

Keep in mind that this will still start a huge amount of I/O operations on your server.

> And the backup job is also showing suspended state

Suspended state simply means that it is waiting on resources, I/O based in your case.

---

**Other improvements**

Check what else is running on the instance, any maintenance plans such as index rebuilds, statistic updates, integrity checks?

You could start logging queries with [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) and perhaps [logging it in a table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/).

Striping your backups accross multiple files can help in reducing backup time. More on that [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5668/sql-server-script-to-automatically-split-database-backups-into-multiple-backup-files/). 
My go to is 4 files but you could test different settings.

Since you are on `sql server 2012`, if you are not using `TDE` you could leverage backup compression as well.

More information on making backups go faster can be found [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/how-to-make-sql-server-backups-go-faster/)